# Binding MvxDialogFragment with ViewModel

Tags: android, mvvm, xamarin.android, mvvmcross, android-dialogfragment

I have ViewModel and DialogFragment for view this VM.
In core I show VM in this way

```
this.ShowViewModel<AnnotationEditViewModel>();
```

i have this code in AnnotationEditDialogFragment.cs

```
[Register("AnnotationEditDialogFragment")]
public class AnnotationEditDialogFragment : MvxDialogFragment<AnnotationEditViewModel>
{
...
public override Dialog OnCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
base.EnsureBindingContextSet(savedInstanceState);
var view = this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.text_annotation_dialog_fragment, null);
var titleAnnotationTextView = view.FindViewById<TextViewWithFont>(Resource.Id.titleAnnotationTextView);
var set = this.CreateBindingSet<AnnotationEditFragment, AnnotationEditViewModel>();
set.Bind(this).For(be => be.CanBeSaved).To(vm => vm.CanBeSaved);
set.Apply();
builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity);
LayoutInflater inflater = Activity.LayoutInflater;
builder.SetView(view);
alertDialog = builder.Create();
return alertDialog;
}
...
}
```

I have request in MainPresenter in Showv method where i can detect this request.

if in MainPresenter i type this code:

```
var textAnnotationDialogFragment = Activity.FragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag(nameof(AnnotationEditFragment)) as AnnotationEditFragment ?? new AnnotationEditFragment();
textAnnotationDialogFragment.Show(Activity.FragmentManager, nameof(AnnotationEditFragment));
```

- I see dialog, but i don't have binding with VM/

if i type this code for ShowViewModel():

```
base.Show(request, fragmentRequest);
```

- I get error that wasn't found any activity or fragment for my VM/
  How can I have dialog with binding to VM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The issues:**

*1. Presenter Handled Request approach - ViewModel Null*

Using this approach the `ViewModel` property of `AnnotationEditFragment` is null as no `ViewModel` has been set on the fragment as it is being created outside of the normal lifecycle Mvx uses when creating normal `MvxFragments`. `MvxDialogFragment` follow a different lifecycle.

*2. Presenter Unhandled Request approach - No Activity*

Using this approach the standard Mvx fragment lifecycle is trying to be executed on the `MvxDialogFragment`. Which requires an Activity to be specified to place the fragment into. This is not the approach we want with the `MvxDialogFragment`.

---

**Solution:**

I believe approach 1 is the closest to getting us a successfully implementation of a working `MvxDialogFragment`. All we need to do is make sure the ViewModel runs through it's lifecycle. So in your `MainPresenter` make sure to create an instance of the `AnnotationEditViewModel` based on the request and assign it to the `AnnotationEditFragment`:

```
protected override void ShowActivity(MvxViewModelRequest request, MvxViewModelRequest fragmentRequest = null)
{
    if (request.ViewModelType == typeof(NamesViewModel))
    {
        var dialog = new AnnotationEditFragment();
        var viewModel = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxViewModelLoader>().LoadViewModel(request, null) as AnnotationEditViewModel;
        dialog.ViewModel = viewModel;
        dialog.Show(Activity.FragmentManager, nameof(AnnotationEditFragment));

        return;
    }

    base.ShowActivity(request, fragmentRequest);
}
```

`IMvxViewModelLoader` is used to make sure the ViewModel is loaded according to the Mvx ViewModel lifecycle standard, [CIRS](https://mvvmcross.com/docs/app-lifecycle#section-how-viewmodels-are-created-in-v3):

> 1. Construction - using IoC for Dependency Injection
> 2. Init() - initialisation of navigation parameters
> 3. ReloadState() - rehydration after tombstoning
> 4. Start() - called when initialisation and rehydration are complete